# Why is the Figaro gem working only if I use erb syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm using the [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) but it only works when I access the env variables inside `config/database.yml` like this:

```
<%= ENV["MYSQL_USERNAME"] %>
```

but not when I try it the way the docs specify:

```
ENV["MYSQL_USERNAME"]
```

or

```
Figaro.env.mysql_username
```

Does anyone know why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their documentation is wrong. If you want to interpolate a non-static value into a YAML file, you have to use the ERB tags. YAML files are generally just static files. Rails processes `database.yml` through an ERB parser, which is why you can interpolate values using ERB syntax.

To put it another way: if you don't use the ERB tags, Rails doesn't know if it should evaluate what you've typed, or if it should treat it as a static value.

Comment: At least in my case Rails treats it as `plain text` without using the ERB tags. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. There are some good resources that you may find useful. I not doing for the sake of upvote.

Answer (score 7):

**[Figaro Gem's](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)** official documentation clearly says (see "Give me an example" section) the following:

> **NOTE:** Figaro uses Rails' standard hooks to initialize. Unfortunately, this hook apparently occurs after database.yml is read.
>   Because of this issue, environment variables created in
>   application.yml don't work inside database.yml.

Upon investigating further I found out few issues were raised regarding this. Steve Richert (creator of Figaro Gem with "laserlemon" Github id) says this on the **[issue #70](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/issues/70)**

> This is a known issue. We use Rails' standard hooks to initialize
>   Figaro before Rails initializes. Unfortunately, this hook apparently
>   occurs after database.yml is read. Trying to circumvent the standard
>   hooks and tie into Rails' initialization elsewhere introduces a host
>   of new problems and makes it very difficult to account for every
>   situation in which the Rails environment is loaded. I'm afraid this
>   falls into the "won't fix" bucket until Rails provides a better (and
>   supported) hook that Figaro can tie into...

**UPDATE**:

As per the **[pull request #100](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/pull/100)** the database.yml config is working with fine latest version of both Rails (like 4.0 and 4.1) and Figaro.

Finally, I **highly recommend reading [Rails Environment Variables](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)** guide by Taylor Mock and Daniel Kehoe. This is a MUST read for all RoR developers.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful info

Comment: +1 for awesome research on the answer PLUS the references. Good work :)

Comment: Glad to help. @DanielKehoe no problem. Its worth mentioning.  Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing `ENV["MYSQL_USERNAME"]` within an `ERB` file then obviously you need to use  `<%= %>` to evaluate and print the evaluated ruby code.

If you simple use `ENV["MYSQL_USERNAME"]` without `<%= %>` then it will not be interpreted by ERB Template Engine. It would be treated as `plain text`.

**EDIT**

Your question did not specify where you are accessing `ENV["MYSQL_USERNAME"]` initially(it was added later after posting comment to my answer) thats why I assumed that it was in ERB file. 
In any `.rb` file you don't need to specify `<%= %>` while accessing `ENV`. But you do need to specify them to access within `.yml` or `.erb` files.

Comment: This is all inside the default config/database.yml